# JPA and aggregate functions. How do I use the result of the query?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm new to ORM stuff and I need some help understanding something.

Let's assume I have the following standard SQL query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(test.testId) AS noTests FROM inspection
LEFT JOIN test ON inspection.inspId = test.inspId
GROUP BY inspection.inspId
```

which I want to use in JPA.

I have an Inspection entity with a one-to-many relationship to a Test entity. (an inspection has many tests)
I tried writing this in JPQL:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT insp, COUNT(???what???) " +
      "FROM Inspection insp LEFT JOIN insp.testList " +  
      "GROUP BY insp.inspId");
```

1) How do I write the COUNT clause? I'd have to apply count to elements from the test table but testList is a collection, so I can't do smth like `COUNT(insp.testList.testId)`

2) Assuming 1 is resolved, what type of object will be returned. It will definitely not be an Inspection object... How do I use the result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. You can give an alias to the joined entity (with `AS`)
2. You can create either a new object, or a `List` with the returned values

So:

```
SELECT new com.yourproject.ResultHolder(insp, COUNT(test.testId)) 
    FROM Inspection insp LEFT JOIN  insp.testList AS test GROUP BY insp.inspId
```

Or

```
SELECT new list(insp, COUNT(test.testId)) 
    FROM Inspection insp LEFT JOIN  insp.testList AS test GROUP BY insp.inspId
```

The result is then accessible either as an instance of `ResultHolder`, or as a `java.util.List`, where the `insp` is `list.get(0)`, and the count is `list.get(1)`

Comment: What are performance implications of using aggregation in JPA queries?