# How do I return a list of joined hibernate entities?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Suppose I have a MySQL table, and entity `tag` in hibernate, where a `tag` is a row in the following

```
id (primary key), tag,    entity id
1,                food,   77
2,                shop,   98
3,                food,   32
...
```

I'd like to return the total counts of the same tag sorted in decreasing number of entries.  Aka,

```
tag,     count
food,    2
shop,    1
...
```

I was told to do something like

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*) `count`
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY tag
 ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

Output:

```
|  TAG | COUNT |
|------|-------|
| food |     2 |
| shop |     1 |
```

However, how do I read this newly created list of entities out from Hibernate?  Do I need to somehow define a new object to read this list out?

The same question goes for say reading an entity (row) that is defined, but just joined with another entity as part of a query.  How do I read out the result?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA and aggregate functions. How do I use the result of the query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911558/jpa-and-aggregate-functions-how-do-i-use-the-result-of-the-query)

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
String query = "SELECT tag, COUNT(*) as count "+
                "FROM table1 " +
                "GROUP BY tag " +
                "ORDER BY count DESC";
```

Additional class

```
public class Result  
{  
   private String tag;
   private int count;
   // getters/ setters
}
```

Create native query

```
  final Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
  final SQLQuery sqlQuery = (SQLQuery) ((HibernateQuery) nativeQuery ).getHibernateQuery(); 
  sqlQuery.addScalar("tag");
  sqlQuery.addScalar("count");
  sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Result.class));
```